# Add Registered Trademark symbol in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, superscript

How do I add registered trademark symbol in Flex?

Answer (score 3):

Use the xml entities

™ `&#8482;`
®  `&#174;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Could you please tell me how to use this in a super script?

Comment: Flash doesn't support `sup` or `sub` tags. There is a workaround here http://blog.ggshow.com/index.php/reference/2007/04/19/how_to_use_subscript_aamp_superscript_in

Comment: @JK: These symbols are already superscript, no further action needed. I.e. b™d

Answer (score 2):

for © you can type Alt + 0169 and it will insert it in place.
for ™ you have Alt + 0153

Answer (score 1):

In what context? For the most part you should be able to include a  ® character (U+00AE Registered Sign) directly.

If your editor can't understand UTF-8, there are various forms of encoding you might use. In an MXML file you could say `&#xAE;`. (That wouldn't work in a CDATA block though.) In an ActionScript string literal you can say `'\xAE'`.